# Click element using CSS selector in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to click an object using css selector on puppeteer, I am using device emulator(iphone X).

I have the following two css  selector for same object,

```
div:nth-of-type(1) > .canvasContentDiv.container_1vt1y2p > div > div:nth-of-type(4) .react-knockout-control > div
```

and

```
[aria-labelledby='pa-gallery-label-1'] [data-control-id='24'] [touch-action]
```

Any help how to do it, tried with following two ways but not working ?

Method 1:

```
const elementHandle = await page.evaluate(() => { const element = document.querySelector("[aria-labelledby='pa-gallery-label-1'] [data-control-id='24'] [touch-action]"); });
await page.waitFor(500);
elementHandle.click();
```

Method 2:

```
 await page.click("[aria-labelledby='pa-gallery-label-1'] [data-control-id='24'] [touch-action]");
```

Comment: Do those css queries return the element you want to click when you load the page in Chrome, using DevTools?

Comment: Yeah, they are returning

Comment: Meant to also ask -- are you emulating iphone X when you test the query in DevTools?

Comment: Please share the page as a [mcve]. This could be caused by one of many different factors: an iframe, a shadow root, JS removing the element, your bot being detected and blocked (often caused by running headlessly), a scroll/visibility/lazy-loading issue, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting a handle this way to detect if your query works correctly at runtime:

```js
const query = "[aria-labelledby='pa-gallery-label-1'] [data-control-id='24'] [touch-action]";
const element = await this.page.$(query);
if (element) {
  await element.click();
  console.log('element clicked');
}
else {
  console.log('element not found');
}
```

If the element is found and clicked, then I would suggest you run the browser in visible mode `{headless: false}`, run the code in VS Code with the debugger attached, and pause execution after clicking. This will allow you to open DevTools in the Chromium instance it has launched and you can inspect what is happening in the console.